# Why is my collision registered when there is no collision?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, xcode6, skphysicsbody

Please bear with me, I've been working with XCode/IOS for a day, so you may need to explain things...

I have a collision method:

```
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact!) {

    if (contact != nil && contact.bodyA != nil && contact.bodyB != nil)
    {
        var firstBody:SKPhysicsBody
        var seconBody:SKPhysicsBody

        if (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask < contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask)
        {
            firstBody = contact.bodyA
            seconBody = contact.bodyB
        }
        else
        {
            firstBody = contact.bodyB
            seconBody = contact.bodyA
        }

        if (firstBody.categoryBitMask & torpedoCategory != 0 && seconBody.categoryBitMask & alienCategory != 0)
        {

            if firstBody.node != nil && seconBody.node != nil {
                torpedodidCollideWithAlien(firstBody.node as SKSpriteNode, alien: seconBody.node as SKSpriteNode)

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Which is triggered by this:

```
    var alien:SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Alien")

    alien.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: alien.texture, size: alien.size)
    alien.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = alienCategory
    alien.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = torpedoCategory
    alien.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = 0
    alien.zPosition = -100000
```

I'm trying to use the pixel collision available in XCode 6.  The issue is that the `didBeginContact` method is triggered when there is no collision, and it is triggered multiple times for one collision.

Am I using the physics system incorrectly?

Here is a link to the full project: https://www.dropbox.com/s/1npctvb99vw2l7x/BubbleBurst.zip

Values for the masks:

```
    let alienCategory:UInt32 = 0x1 << 1    
    let torpedoCategory:UInt32 = 0x1 << 0
```

Comment: What values do you have for `alienCategory` and `torpedoCategory`? I can't download your project because Dropbox is blocked by company's firewall.

Comment: @BrunoWerminghoff - I added the extra detail to the bottom of the question.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not really your answer, but it might help you to find out the actual answer.

`I'm trying to use the pixel collision available in XCode 6. The issue is that the didBeginContact method is triggered when there is no collision, and it is triggered multiple times for one collision.`

Collision and contact are different things. Use `contactTestBitMask` for detecting contacts (what you're doing) and `collisionBitMask` to enable the physics related to those contacts (collision itself). In more practical terms, `contactTestBitMask` should be used to handle something using your code, and `collisionBitMask` is used by SpriteKit to make, for example, an object bounce when it hits another object.

If you use the `collisionBitMask`, you'll probably get rid of your second problem ("[didBeginContact] triggered multiple times for one collision").

For your first issue ("didBeginContact [...] triggered when there is no collision"), I'd try to change your `alien.physicsBody`. I'm gonna totally guess in this part, but maybe your image is like 300x300 and you want your alien to have a pixel size of 150x150. Maybe your `alien.physicsBody` is larger than it looks, and therefore its physics body is touching the other object's physics body before the visual representation does the same.

Comment: The sprite for the alien is trimmed around the edges, not like 30px off like the ball collides with in code.  I read that using `SKPhysicsBody` with a texture and size in XCode6 allows pixel based collisions where the size of the sprite is largely unimportant, and it can utilise alpha values in your sprite to detect where the pixels to collide with are.  I want to detect a collision in my code on a complex shape using the per-pixel collision system available in swift/xcode6.  Also, collision/contact may be different things in SK, however in my head they are one and the same ;-)

Answer (score 0):

In your viewController where you set up your SKView I recommend turning this on while you get this sorted out.

```
skView.showsPhysics = true
```

As for contact happening multiple times, that is completely normal. If two nodes you are telling SpriteKit to test for contact overlap it will read as contact each run of the loop (didSimulatePhysics). Let's say you want a torpedo to destroy an alien, one or both need to be removed from the scene to stop contact from being read again (optionally hidden or moved). Or for example if you want it to take multiple torpedoes to destroy the alien, the torpedo needs to be removed/moved on contact.

As Bruno mentioned, collision in SpriteKit means two objects can act as solid bodies that get in each others way. A player might collide with a wall (can't pass through it), but the player may be able to pass through monsters.

Also your didBeginContact code could be a lot more simple. Here is an example that tests if a player has hit one of three other physics body contactBitMasks.

```
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    var other:SKPhysicsBody = contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == Contact.Player ? contact.bodyB : contact.bodyA

    if other.categoryBitMask == Contact.Scene {
        // Do stuff for player hitting scene edge
    } else if other.categoryBitMask == Contact.Object {
        // Do stuff for player hitting the hazards
    } else if other.categoryBitMask == Contact.Score {
       // Do stuff for player scoring points
    }
}
```